# PHP/AJAX - advice on replacing iFrame with DIV (combined with AJAX)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, iframe

I currently have a webpage where an iframe contains data that is stored into an invisible form, and I want to replace that iFrame, with a div, where the content is being changed/updated via AJAX.

> *If you dont feel like reading all this, you can skip to the end and read my main question.*

**Now, the complicated part** is that the form contains all the important and used data in an invisible form, which needs to be send via POST. But, the page also includes a form that can send data via GET. And: I've setup the forms like this, that the php file recieves the form data as an array.

**At the moment it works like this:**
The iFrame shows the data, and stores it in an invisible form. When you want the page to refresh automatically, every 30 seconds, you click a button, and you get redirected to another page, which recieves the data from the previous page, using POST.
When you're on the auto-refreshing page, I use Javascript to automatically submit the form containing all the important data, to refresh the page.

Resubmitting the page is nessecary because I use PHP to do some important calculations with the data I'm using. Moving all this functionality to Javascript is not an option.

Just to be clear, here is a very brief description of my case:

> **Main page**: 2 forms, 1 POST setup so variables are in 1 array, 1 GET with 6 variables.
>   *The GET form could be modified to an AJAX function, as it only includes 6 variables*
>
> **Auto update page**: 2 forms, same as before. Though this POST form is auto-submitted via Javascript every 30 seconds (to update the PHP
>   functions output).

So, my main question is:
**Can I, and if so how, recieve an array from a POST form in AJAX, and then send it as an array to a php page?**

EDIT:
Here is some of the code for submitting the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function paginarefresh() {
    document.forms["updateform"].submit();
}
var paginatimer = setInterval(paginarefresh, 60000);
</script>
```

and the form is build up like this:

```
echo '<form action="data-reis-refresh.php" id="updateform" name="update" method="POST" style="width: 100px;">';
echo '<input type="submit" class="submit replaced" value="Volg deze trein" name="submit-search"/>';
if (round($afgelegdpercentage*100,1)==100) {
echo ' <a href="#" class="submit button"><span style="text-align: center;">Deze trein is al aangekomen</span></a>';
    } else {
echo ' <a href="javascript:submitform(\'update\')" class="submit button"><span style="text-align: center;">Ververs gegevens (automatisch elke minuut)</span></a>';
}
echo '<input type="hidden" name="provincie" value="'.$provincie.'">
      <input type="hidden" name="reisdata[Overstap]" value="'.$reisdata["Overstap"].'">
      <input type="hidden" name="reisdata[Van]" value="'.$reisdata["Van"].'">
```

but then longer (a lot longer, and with changing length);

I'm using this for all my AJAX requests: [though I change it for different uses]

```
// Algemene functie om een xmlHttp object te maken. Via dit object kunnen we later Ajax calls plaatsen

function GetXmlHttpObjectReisData() {
    var xmlHttp;
    try { // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    catch (e) { // Internet Explorer
        try { xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) {
            try { xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } 
            catch (e) {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
function CallAjaxReisDataFunction(serverScript,arguments)
{
    var xmlHttp = new GetXmlHttpObjectReisData(); // Functie welke wordt uitgevoerd als de call naar de server klaar is State 4)
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) 
        {
            handleReisDataResult(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    // Ajax call (Request naar de server met eventuele parameters (arguments))
    xmlHttp.open("POST", serverScript, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", arguments.length);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlHttp.send(arguments);
}

function callReisDataServer(serverScript,van,naar)
{
    CallAjaxReisDataFunction(serverScript,"?&reisdata=" + reisdata);
}

function handleReisDataResult(responseText)
{
    document.getElementById('reis').innerHTML = responseText;
}
```

Comment: The short answer is yes. The long answer needs to see (some of) your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've added some code now. How would you recommend doing this?

Comment: Can you post example of form data you need to GET and POST?

Comment: I've added that to the start post now. I've also posted the code I use to send the data via AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I ended up using jQuery .post() and .get().
Those are extremely easy to use and a lot faster and more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

JS code:

```
var postdata = {"provincie":"123","reisdata":{"Overstap":"234","Van":"345"}};
var post = "";
var url = "data-reis-refresh.php";
var key, subkey;
for (key in postdata) {
    if (typeof(postdata[key]) == object) {
        for (subkey in postdata[key]) {
            if (post != "") post += "&";
            post += key + "%5B" + subkey + "%5D=" + postdata[key][subkey];
        }
    }
    else post += key + "=" + postdata[key];
}
req.open("POST", url, true);
req.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", post.length);
req.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
req.send(post);
```

And to transfer associative array back from PHP to JS:

In PHP script, called from AJAX request:

```
echo "(".json_encode($hash).")";
```

In JS code, parsing the result:

```
var hash = eval(response);
```

Comment: What language is that, PHP or Javascript? Because I need to send the array to Javascript from the php page, and then send it from the Javascript script to another PHP page. ANd the results of that request (AJAX) will then replace the existing HTML.

If I would do this with Javascript, I'd have to tear apart my associative array and someone put it all in one line... That doesn't seem easy to me...

Comment: This looks great, I think I understand what you do in the JS code. However, those lines beneath it, I do not understand:
In the PHP file, I just request the POST data, like $_POST["provincie"] and $_POST["reisdata"] ? I don't really get that part.
Also, why do you use json_encode? and the JS eval() ? (I tried looking up what eval does, but couldn't really figure it out)

Comment: Those lines explain how to transfer data back to JS once you get associative array $hash ready to send as result of AJAX request.
And JS part (eval) parses responseText of AJAX request to get $hash as JS associative array.
I did not post any code to use $_POST in PHP since i guess you know how to do it.

Comment: @mephisto123 While I can't fault your general approach, an `eval()` of raw response text is *not* the way to go. You should use [Douglas Crockford's JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). But +1 anyway.

Comment: @mephisto123 : so, let me see if I get this:
I submit the form to my AJAX function.
There I used your script to convert the associative array into a piece of POST data.
But then, how do I read it in php? For example just by using $_POST["reisdata"] ?
I then do not need json_decode and eval(), right? Or am I missing something? **Thank you very very very much for your help btw!**

Comment: DaveRandom, it depends on quality of your code. If your code has some security flaws, it is dangerous to use eval(). Otherwise I don't see any reason not to do so. It is native language feature.

Comment: laarsk, yes, just use $_POST[] as you did with usual HTML form.
You will need json_encode() and eval() ONLY if you want to pass some associative array as a result of AJAX request BACK from PHP to JS.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you sooo much! I will try this out tomorrow!
**Now I know once again why I love stackoverflow!**

Comment: Feel free to post any other questions regarding this issue, I'll try to help. Most of the code were untested, I could do some mistakes.

Comment: Yeah, I'll report back on my progress :)

Comment: Ok, I have a question now, kinda weird I didn't notice it yesterday: I have setup an array in the HTML form, which I send to the AJAX function. In your code you declare the arrays by hand, but I need a method that the Javascript/AJAX function will read the array (from the POST data from the form) and then pass it on to the PHP file. How can I make it recieve the array? You gave the code for sending a Javascript array to PHP, but not for the part that handles the part where Javascript recieves the array... Am I right?

Comment: But this form is generated somehow in your JS or PHP code. You gotta generate JS logic to format data in this form as single POST string aswell. It depends on how you build that form in your code. Can't help without seeing it.